# What is the best way to set the default instance for a final private field with optional parameter?

Tags: dart

Given a class with final private field _bar:

```
class Foo() {

final Bar _bar;

    Foo({Bar bar}) : _bar = bar {

        //error: list cannot be used as setter, it is final
       _bar = new Bar();
    }

}
```

Attempting to set it in the parameter list results in this error

```
//error: default values of an object must be constant
Foo({Bar bar: new Bar()}) : _bar = bar ..
```

I'd like to keep the optional parameter so that I can inject mocks during unit tests. What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class Foo {
  final Bar _bar;
  Foo({Bar bar}) : _bar = bar != null ? bar : new Bar();
}
```

Comment: Didn't know that. Would be interesting what's the point in allowing it in the initializer list but not as default value.

Comment: The main difference is when you explicitaly set the optional parameter with `null`. With the default value, the field will be equal to `null` though with this initializer list it will be equal to `new Bar()`

Comment: That wasn't what I meant. I'm curious why a non-const value is allowed in the initializer list but not as default value.

Comment: Indeed. I don't know.

Comment: The default value is part of the function signature - it's documented in the DartDoc, and you must not override a function with a default value with a function with a different default value. That only works if the value is known without evaluating a runtime expression. Also, there isn't any clear time where it should be evaluated at runtime. It's a default *value*, so you want the same value every time the function is called, and it would be slightly odd (but only slightly) if it was evaluated the first time the function is called. All in all, it makes everything much simpler if it is const.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use static methods when a logic is complex thing.

```
class Foo {
  final Object _field1;

  Foo({Object value1}) : this._field1 = _setUpField1(value1);

  static Object _setUpField1(Object value) {
    // Some complex logic
    return value;
  }
}
```